# Strategy for Pinterest Product Hunt style modals and routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-redux

(I am using the latest versions of React, [React-Router](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router) and [React-Aria-Modal](https://github.com/davidtheclark/react-aria-modal))

I am trying to create Routing behavior like the one seen on Pinterest or Product Hunt. For those unfamiliar, it boils down to having a Feed of Things (pins, products, etc) in a preview mode. Clicking on the name or some 'view more' link in that preview, opens the Thing in a modal and changes the route accordingly. If I was to copy-paste that URL, or refresh the page, the Thing now renders like a page.

So, on the 'View More' `Link` component, I set up the state (view = Modal) and in the `Thing` component to see if whether to render in a Modal or not.

So, essentially:

```
<App>
  <Feed>
    {things.map((thingId) => <Thing id={thingId} />)}
  </Feed>
</App>
```

Within a `Thing`, it roughly looks like this:

```
renderThing() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Name />
      <Link 
        to={"/things/ + this.props.id} 
        state = {{
          view: "Modal"
        }}
      > 
        View More 
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
}

render() {
  if(this.state.view == 'Modal'){
    return (<AriaModal>{renderThing()</AriaModal>);
  } else {
    return renderThing();
  }
}
```

I run into an issue where now the page background disappears on clicking on a link while the modal does show up. I imagine this is due to the navigation by clicking on the link.

React-Router has an [example like this](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/tree/master/examples/pinterest) which solves this but that has some issues as well. They seem to essentially store the previous children at the `App` level and render that in addition to the requested Modal/Route - essentially causing a re-render of the entire feed which feels neither performant nor clean.

Moreover, if 'Next/Previous' style interaction was to be set up, it seems the entire background would be loaded everytime router state was updated by clicking on 'Next/Previous' which also feels unnecessary.

So, I am wondering how best to think about setting this up - so that the previous page still shows up in the background and the route is updated as well.

Any thoughts would be super appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I've written a [CodePen that demonstrates Pinterest routing](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/akYKQx). It uses the [Navigation router](http://grahammendick.github.io/navigation/) instead of the React Router but I hope you're open to that. You can see that that if the `oldState` is populated then the list is visible and I render into the modal div. If the `oldState` is empty then the list isn't visible and I render into the container div. You can try this out by opening one of the Hyperlinks in a new tab. If you've got any questions about the code, please let me know.

```
var {StateNavigator} = Navigation;
var {NavigationLink} = NavigationReact;

var Thing = ({thing}) => <h2>{thing}</h2>;

var Things = ({things, stateNavigator}) => (
  <div>
    <ul>
      {things.map(thing => 
        <li key={thing}>
          <NavigationLink
            stateKey="thing"
            navigationData={{thing: thing}}
            stateNavigator={stateNavigator}>
            {thing}
          </NavigationLink>
        </li>
      )}
    </ul>
    <div id="modal"></div>
  </div>
);

var stateNavigator = new StateNavigator([
  {key: 'things', route: ''},
  {key: 'thing', route: 'thing'}
]);

var THINGS = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'];

stateNavigator.states.things.navigated = () => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Things things={THINGS} stateNavigator={stateNavigator} />,
    document.getElementById('container')
  );
};

stateNavigator.states.thing.navigated = (data) => {
  var oldState = stateNavigator.stateContext.oldState;
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Thing thing={data.thing} />,
    document.getElementById(oldState ? 'modal' : 'container')
  );
};

stateNavigator.start();
```